# Save Image with Text label to Photo Library in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to save image with the text label in the foreground of the image to photo library.I already worked out how to open the camera roll,taking picture and saving photo to the photo library.Currently, I am using screenshot function to capture the screen view.it works ok. But, I am not really satisfied with the result. Because,I have navigation bar and toolbar running in the same view.So,I have to use gesture recogniser function to hide both bars and long press gesture to save the screenshot to the photo library. It's looks like, I am doing too much coding to achieve a single function.I am looking for simple and effective solution.

My code below..

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
   imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
   imagePicker.delegate = self
   imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
   imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
   presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Save Button
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

    let sourceImage = imageView.image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage!.size);
    let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let rect:CGRect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceImage!.size.width, sourceImage!.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, sourceImage!.CGImage);

    // draw your text here

    let resultImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
label.text = label.text

}

func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    if error == nil {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you need is to add a text to an image and then save the result to the Photo Library. Is that it?

To add the text label to the image, you can use the [Core Graphics framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/index.html). Here's a start:

```
UIImage *sourceImage = ...

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height);

CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, sourceImage.CGImage);

// draw your text here

UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You'll probably need the [UIKit Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/) and the [CGContext Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/) as well.

Comment: Yes your right and Your answer make sense. but still i don't know how to set the resultImage.i am uploading my code. please take a look.Thanks

Comment: Replace `imageView.image` in `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)` with `resultImage`. Also remember to draw the text to the graphics context...

Comment: sorry to ask you again.can you elaborate how to draw the text the graphics context.I am looking at CGContext Reference doc.it looks more Advanced to me and i am not familiar with core graphics.can you point me out which function i have to use.Thanks